# jQuery selector for bigger or smaller than

Tags: jquery

I have elements that I want to choose from, 
and I want to choose only the elements that have margin-left 
smaller than 100 pixels but bigger than 0.

Is that possible in jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) (assuming `elements` is a jQuery object):

```
elements.filter(function() {
    var margin = parseInt(this.style.marginLeft, 10);
    return  margin > 0 && margin < 100;
}).something();
```